# JSON-LD Expansion

Tags: json, json-ld

The [JSON-LD Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/) (an example JSON-LD processor) doesn't expand content (property value) with a "compact IRI" ("example:dog") like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "example": "https://example.com/vocab#"
  },
  "animal": "example:dog"
}
```

into this full IRI ("https://example.com/vocab#dog"):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "example": "https://example.com/vocab#"
  },
  "animal": "https://example.com/vocab#dog"
}
```

Is this a fault of the particular JSON-LD processor I used? Or is this my (and [ChatGPT's](https://chat.openai.com/share/c1bd4d17-e7c0-46de-b32c-04994ca9845d)) misunderstanding of [JSON-LD Expansion](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld-api/#expansion) using @context?

Comment: This does not expand into any RDF because `animal` is missing its IRI.

Answer (score 0):

@IS4 is right.  When I make a proper JSON-LD instance with an [SKOS](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-primer/) animal Collection with SKOS cat and dog Concepts...

```
{
  "@context": {
    "skos": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#",
    "example": "https://example.com/vocab#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "example:animals_collection",
      "@type": "skos:Collection",
      "skos:member": [
        {
          "@id": "example:cat",
          "@type": "skos:Concept",
          "skos:prefLabel": "Cat"
        },
        {
          "@id": "example:dog",
          "@type": "skos:Concept",
          "skos:prefLabel": "Dog"
        }         
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

...the JSON-LD Expansion is what I want, namely @id properties reflect expanded IRI's for the collection as well as each member (dog, cat) of the SKOS Collection (shown in compacted format):

```
{
  "@id": "https://example.com/vocab#animals_collection",
  "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Collection",
  "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#member": [
    {
      "@id": "https://example.com/vocab#cat",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept",
      "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel": "Cat"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://example.com/vocab#dog",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept",
      "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel": "Dog"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

To get the desired form of output we must:

1. Declare a vocabulary for the term `animal`.
2. Declare that the type of `animal` is `@id` (i.e. an IRI).
3. Use compaction instead of expansion.

**Details**

The exhibited example input expands to any empty result ([playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22example%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%7D%2C%22animal%22%3A%22example%3Adog%22%7D)):

```json
[]
```

The first problem (as noted in the comments), is that a triple is not generated for the `animal` term because that term has no mapping to an IRI.  A simple fix for this is to add a `@vocab` term to the context ([playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22example%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%7D%2C%22animal%22%3A%22example%3Adog%22%7D)):

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocab#",
    "example": "https://example.com/vocab#"
  },
  "animal": "example:dog"
}
```

Now we will get the following expanded form:

```json
[
  {
    "https://example.com/vocab#animal": [
      {
        "@value": "example:dog"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which brings us to the next problem: Why isn't `example:dog` expanded into an IRI?  The answer is that string-valued terms are presumed to be just simple strings by default.  To have them interpreted as IRIs, we must declare the type of the `animal` term to be `@id` ([playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22example%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22animal%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%2C%22animal%22%3A%22example%3Adog%22%7D)):

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocab#",
    "example": "https://example.com/vocab#",
    "animal": {"@type": "@id"}
  },
  "animal": "example:dog"
}
```

Now we will get the following expanded form:

```json
[
  {
    "https://example.com/vocab#animal": [
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/vocab#dog"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The third problem is that this expanded form does not resemble the desired result exhibited in the question.  To get (close to) that, we must use *compaction* instead of *expansion*.  For example, we can compact with the following framing document ([playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22example%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22animal%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%2C%22animal%22%3A%22example%3Adog%22%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22animal%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%7D)):

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocab#",
    "animal": {
      "@type": "@id"
    }
  }
}
```

... to obtain a result which resembles the original request (but with a different context):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocab#",
    "animal": {
      "@type": "@id"
    }
  },
  "animal": "https://example.com/vocab#dog"
}
```